# How to show only local drives and folders from the Browse dialog when installing using NSIS?

Tags: nsis

Once opened the browse dialog when installing using NSIS, it is showing the list of drivers, folders, mapped drives, removable drives and network folders. How to filter it and show only the local drives and folders from the Browse dialog?

Comment: Why? Why should you force your users to give up control of their machine?

Comment: Because it is showing the removable drives and the shared drives connected to the computer and there is no use to show those drives that the user don't have the control.

Comment: Maybe the user has a removable drive always connected and that is where they prefer to install their programs.

Comment: No, as per the user requirement i should display only the local drives and should restrict displaying the other drives.

Comment: Is there any option to do that? or is there any option to stop access to that drive?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot change the way the directory page works, you would have to write a custom page and a custom plug-in if you want to filter the folder dialog.

You can however validate the directory and block the user from moving to the next page:

```
!include LogicLib.nsh
Page Directory
Page InstFiles

!define /IfNDef DRIVE_FIXED 3
Function .onVerifyInstDir
StrCpy $0 $InstDir 1 
System::Call 'KERNEL32::GetDriveType(t"$0:\")i.r0'
${If} $0 <> ${DRIVE_FIXED}
    Abort
${EndIf}
FunctionEnd
```

In this specific case that might not be a good idea because the user has no idea why they can't click the next/install button.

Instead you should stop with a message when the user tries to leave the page:

```
!include LogicLib.nsh
Page Directory "" "" ValidateDirPage
Page InstFiles

!define /IfNDef DRIVE_FIXED 3
Function ValidateDirPage
StrCpy $0 $InstDir 1 
System::Call 'KERNEL32::GetDriveType(t"$0:\")i.r0'
${If} $0 <> ${DRIVE_FIXED}
    MessageBox MB_ICONSTOP "You must specify a local fixed drive for some reason!"
    Abort
${EndIf}
FunctionEnd
```

Note: Some USB storage devices will identify as a fixed drive.

Even if you do all this you cannot stop people from installing to a different drive type. They could temporarily change their drive letters, install, and then change them back etc.